# Return free space of all drives on a server using powershell

Tags: powershell

If the free space of a drive is 100% free and I set the minimum threshold space to 25%, the script incorrect reports that the drive is below threshold.. meaning 100 < 25
Although If I were to replace 
$FreePercent = "{0:N0}" -f (100 * $objDisk.FreeSpace/$objDisk.Size)  with 
$FreePercent =  (100 * $objDisk.FreeSpace/$objDisk.Size) ...
I get correct results.
How do i fix the rounding off problem.
Here is my code

```
# For Loop -  get % free space of all drives
#Define Variables
$Notify = 0
$MinFreePercent = "25"
#$FileDriveSpace = "c:\temp\DriveSpace.txt"
$ComputerName = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).name
$OutArray = @()

$outarray += "Disk space Alerts and Utilizations on server $ComputerName"
$AllDisks = get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter “DriveType = 3"
#Omit the a, b drives if exist
$AllDisks = $AllDisks | ? { $_.DeviceID -notmatch "[ab]:"}
foreach ($objdisk in $AllDisks) 
{ 
   #$FreePercent = "{0:P0} " -f ($objDisk.FreeSpace/$objDisk.Size) 
   $FreePercent = "{0:N0}" -f (100 * $objDisk.FreeSpace/$objDisk.Size) 


   If ($FreePercent -lt $MinFreePercent) 
      { 
        $Threshold = "Threshold Reached" 
        $Notify = 1
      }
   Else
      { $Threshold = "N/A"}

   $DeviceId = $objDisk.DeviceID
   $myobj = "" | Select "Drive","PercentFreeSpace", "Threshold"
   $myobj.Drive = $DeviceId
   $myobj.PercentFreeSpace = $FreePercent
   $myobj.Threshold = $Threshold

   $outLine = $DeviceId + " " + $FreePercent + " " + $Threshold + " " + $MinFreePercent
   $outLine

   #Add the object to the out-array
   $outarray += $myobj
   #Wipe the object just to be sure
   $myobj = $null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is the `-f` or formatting operator.  It's taking your awesome drive percent free `[int]` and turning it into a plain old boring `[string]`.  I personally use the `[math]` accelerator and call the round method.

`[math]::Round($mynumber,0)`

You could also save yourself some time by looking in the technet gallery for this type of thing:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-HardDrive-0eef638f

I don't remember if that version returns data as a string or an integer but you'll see an example of the round method in action.

Comment: Thanks Jason. That explains it